# How do I open a Word Document as an Editable file using an Intent on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to open a docx file in Word on Android using an Intent, but it always opens Read Only (Word prompts to say it is read only).

The file IS read-write in other apps that can edit a docx (e.g. WPS Office).  Only Microsoft Word is the issue.

```
        String fileUrl = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.docx";
    File file = new File(fileUrl);
    String mime = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";

    Uri theUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.example.testint.fileprovider",
                file);
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType(theUri, mime);

    startActivity(intent);
```

I have run an Intent Intercept with several other apps. ASUS File Manager and ASTRO file manager and File Manager 1.36 are all able to open Word documents as Read/Write using content:// and do not have the read only issue. The intents look the same as my intent, so I cannot see how they can work, when this does not.

This is from ASUS file manager:

```
    intent://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/Documents/Test.docx#Intent;scheme=content;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;launchFlags=0x3000000;end 
------------ 
ACTION: android.intent.action.VIEW 
DATA: content://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/Documents/Test.docx 
MIME: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document 
URI: intent://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/Documents/Test.docx#Intent;scheme=content;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;launchFlags=0x3000000;end 
FLAGS: 
FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT 
FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP
```

Has anyone else here managed to open Word documents for read AND write ok?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Just wrote a technical documentation what I still found out: https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator-android/issues/150#issuecomment-514401775
Microsoft has to fix this problem as soon as possible!

Comment: No, still no luck for me yet.  Your documentation was interesting.   I still cannot see how those two file manager apps I listed CAN do this with word read/write.  Did you look at those?

Comment: Just rechecked, on my device (OP3T LOS version 16.0) the intent of the ASUS file manager looks like this and Word has NO write access: ` {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/aeq_dpunkt.doc typ=application/msword flg=0x80003 cmp=com.microsoft.office.word/.WordActivity}` oooh no, just found out, that there is a difference between .doc and .docx files. .docx has write permission in ASUS file manager. Will check my code again with this new input!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old file format e.g. `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../hello.docx` or a content provider e.g. `content://org.cryptomator.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/org.cryptomator/cache/decrypted/hallo.docx` BUT the file is not allowed to be in the app's internal storage. Then the files are writable!

Files with e.g. the `.doc` extension aren't writable or files located in internal storage aren't writable as well. Here you can find a short overview: https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator-android/issues/150#issuecomment-514401775

Comment: I have actually been experimenting with my own content providers. This does indeed allow a Word edit.  I have another issue on top of this, and that is that I have to wrap the project for an MDM deployment, and that doesn't appear to work with a custom content provider - only the built in one!

Comment: @Sparky with your own implementation of a content providers you can edit Word files in internal storage of the app?

Comment: It was a while back and I had tried many things ;-)   I just checked, and currently it is using getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)